# "Translate me" or "Translate for me"?

Tags: prepositions

Which of these prepositions sound more natural in the following context?

> Translate **to me** this word **to/ into** English, please.

or

> Translate **for me** this word **to/ into** English, please.?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a short answer, I would say that *for* is more natural.

Generally speaking, however, *for* is used with the verb and *to* with the noun. (But not always.)

So, I could say:

> I'm **translating** this Spanish text into English **for** the English-speaking tour guide and providing the **translation to** the tourists.

---

If I hand you a book in Greek I might say:

> ✔ Translate this **for** me.
>   ✔ Please translate this *into English* **for** me.

By saying that, I can either mean that I simply want you to translate it (perhaps write down the English equivalent) or I can mean that I want you to translate it in your head and then read it out loud. Context should determine which I want.

Generally speaking, the following would not be said in the same situation:

> ✘ Translate this **to** me.

Although understood to mean *translate it* ***for*** *me and then read it* ***to*** *me*, and not actually wrong, it would be nonstandard.

But consider the following:

> ✔ *Translate* it and *read* it **to** me.
>   ✔ *Read* this *translation* **to** me.

---

Strangely, the use of *to* becomes more acceptable when it's a group of people being referred to.

For instance, I could also hand you the same book, point to a group of people, and say:

> ✔ Translate this **to** them.

However, it would be just as normal (if not more so) to hear:

> ✔ Translate this **for** them.

**Note**: Some people might disagree with the **to** version sounding natural. I'm not sure if it only sounds okay to me. If in doubt, I would choose the **for** version.

---

But even more strangely, this does not sound normal:

> ✘ Translate this *into English* **to** them.

I would not say that. Rather, I would say:

> ✔ Translate this *into English* **for** them.

I am at a loss to explain why, other than falling back on simply saying that's how it's done. (So, this is one of those inexplicable idiomatic things.)